# Exportar un DataGridView a una plantilla de excel

Tags: c#, datagrid

Como exportar datos del `DataGridView` a celdas especificas de Excel.

Utulizo esta libreria para hacer la exportacion

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Con este `For` recorro las filas y columnas del `DataGridView` para exportar a excel pero querio que sean exportadas a un rango especifico de columunas en excel. Como puedo hacer esto?

Con esto logro que los datos se imprimar en en la columna A1

Pero quiere que empieze a escribir apartir de la B11 a la B40

```
            for (int i = 0; i < reporte.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < reporte.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                if ((reporte.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)
                {
                    hoja.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = reporte.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Que librería usas para trabajar con excel?, es un dato muy importante en el contexto de tu pregunta

Comment: using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: Lo que no logras hacer es que, dentro del excel comience a escribir la tabla dentro de una celda especifica? no me queda muy claro cual es tu duda, ¿qué obtienes ahora? y ¿qué esperas obtener?, agrega eso a la pregunta así se entiende bien!

Comment: No logro que el contenido del DataGridView se importado a las columnas especificas que necesito. Con ese codigo solo logro que los datos sean exportardos a excel pero en las primeras columas

Comment: Al orden de las columnas te referis? o a la posición donde empiezan a escribirse las columnas en excel?

Comment: Ala posicion de los datos del DataGridView  en el excel

Comment: A donde queres que se escriban, y donde se escriben con tu código actual? agrega eso a la pregunta porfavor!

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/3ea82237-ab11-40ad-951e-3bb332410023/how-do-i-export-specific-datagridview-cells-to-specific-cells-in-excel?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int fila = 11;//la posición de la fila
int columna = 2;//la posición de la columna

foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)//recorres las filas
{
    if (!item.IsNewRow)//cuando llegue al punto de una fila nueva no seguira
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Cells.Count; i++)//iteras la cantida de columnas que tiene la fila
        {
             hoja.Cells[fila, columna] = item.Cells[i].Value.ToString();//escribes el valor en la fila y columna asignada.
             columna++;//incrementas la columna
        }
        columna = 2;//cuando termina de escribir reinicias la columna
        fila++;//incrementas la fila.
    }
}
```

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2882#2882), por favor explica tus respuestas!

Answer (score 3):

Sin conocer muy bien la librería [`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel?view=excel-pia), asumo que una solución muy sencilla sería jugando con los índices.

Sabemos que `hoja.Cells[Fila,Columna] = valor`, por lo que podemos hacer algo así..

```
int fila = 11;
int col = 2; //representa columna b

for (int i = 0; i < reporte.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    //Si queres cortar al llegar a la fila 40, bastaría con un if y break
    if((fila+i)==41){break;}
    for (int j = 0; j < reporte.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if ((reporte.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value == null) == false)
        {
            hoja.Cells[i + fila, j + col] = reporte.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

De esta manera, empezaríamos a escribir en la columna 2 (B) y la fila 11